# Program type already present: com.reactnativecommunity.picker.BuildConfig

Tags: react-native, react-native-picker-select

**Using react-native-picker/picker library**

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:multiDexListDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Error while merging dex archives:
> Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
> Program type already present: com.reactnativecommunity.picker.BuildConfig

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```sh
npm uninstall @react-native-community/picker
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by uninstalling this
@react-native-community/picker

npm uninstall @react-native-community/picker